# Soft keyboard, Delphi Tokyo

Tags: android, delphi

I have in my app Edit box and when user enters in Edit box Keyboard pops up (That is ok), but when I want to hide Keyboard 
I Click hardware back buttton or I click outside Edit box app returns in previous form.

I tried with this code, and this code returns me on previous form

```
var
  FService : IFMXVirtualKeyboardService;
begin
  if Key = vkHardwareBack then
  begin
    TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService(IFMXVirtualKeyboardService, IInterface(FService));
    if (FService <> nil) and (TVirtualKeyboardState.Visible in FService.VirtualKeyBoardState) then
    begin
      // Back button pressed, keyboard visible, so do nothing...
      Key := 0;
      FService.HideVirtualKeyboard;
    end else
    begin
      Key := 0;
    end;
  end;
```

Thank you

Comment: "it doesn't work" is never a valid problem description. Please [edit] your question to explain *how* it doesn't work. Do you get an error? Does nothing happen at all? Does it do something unexpected instead?

Comment: Thanks... I changed.